# I brought a car with a sticker on the copper strip on the rear mirror

Tags: electrical, car, window, rear

does anyone know a way of removing the sticker from the rear without destroying the rear copper strip? ( it is the one that heats up when you turn it on)
I am afraid of it stripping if i remove it the regular old fashion way and making it useless. is there a special way or something of some sorts? any help would be greatly appreciated. zoom zoom

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What "copper strip"? From where? From what vehicle? What kind of sticker? What have you tried to use thus far which has failed? Please edit your question and provide enough pertinent detail so we can answer your question intelligently.

Comment: A photo might be useful here.

Comment: Do you mean the rear defroster?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using heat from a hair dryer to heat up the sticker so that the adhesive loosens and then you can carefully peel the sticker off.

Answer (score 0):

Peel as much off in the area no over the heating trace. Then apply Goo Gone to the sticker to dissolve the adhesive. Use a plastic tool to remove the r

Comment: That "Goo Gone" may dissolve the copper strip glue as well causing more issues...

Comment: Goo Gon is an oil activated product. It's not a xylene type. Got any better ideas of how to get the label off or do you just come on to criticize everybody else's suggestions? Notice you do a lot of that.

Comment: can you guarantee that Goo Gone will not affect any other part of the window, copper strip or possible surface treatments? Have you tested?

Comment: Goo Gone is just concentrated citrus oil. It shouldn't have any affect on the defroster wires.